# Arduino Freeboard.io connection via PubNub

Tags: arduino, iot, arduino-uno, pubnub, freeboard

I am trying to send RGB led values to freeboard.io via PubNub. I am sequentially sending R B G values in loop through Arduino but it always misses the middle one. It sends R but after that goes G value than now its time for R but this time B is sent. There was an answer to a related question that suggests a workaround with changing stop function PubNub.cpp instead of waiting for a return message it directly stops the client but it didn't solve my problem either.How can i fix this situation? Images are below.
 
[Arduino side R B G values sent sequentially, Nope means sending is failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA7NJ.png)
[I have changed the stop function with previously answered question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GZmH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Publish and subscribe APIs (instead of send()) directly than the iotconnector.h.

[Check out our Arduino example in github](https://github.com/pubnub/arduino/tree/master/examples).